# Trap key combination and insert string into keyboard buffer

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, user32

The application will run minimized and is used to insert data into applications when the user requests it by a key combination. So using the NuGet package KeystrokeAPI I have made an application that sniffs keystrokes looking for ctrl+alt+w. When that is detected the string "Hello" is inserted into the keyboard buffer using sendKeys. 
The problem I am having is that the sendKeys sends the keys into the sniffer application, not the foreground application that the user was in.

In the code below character.CurrentWindow is the IntPtr returned from User32.dll GetForegroundWindow()

```
using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
{
    api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) =>
    {
        if (character.KeyCode == KeyCode.W && character.CtrlPressed && character.AltPressed)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(character.CurrentWindow);
            SendKeys.Send("Hello");
        }

        Console.Write(character);
    });
    Application.Run();
}
```

The foreground application doesn't get "Hello".

Comment: You could use PostMessage (or similar) to send WM_CHAR message to send keystrokes to which ever window you want. Also I don't understand what you mean by "current application" vs "the one the user was in". I believe by definition the one the user is in is the foreground app aka current app. Whichever window has focus will receive input messages - unless a hook prevents that.

Comment: Yes @user2460798 you are right, that worked.